# R subset df based on multiple columns from another data frame

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to find a more succinct way to filter a data frame using rows from another data frame (I am currently using a loop).

For example, suppose you have the following data frame df1 consisting of quantities of apples, pears, lemons and oranges. There is also a 5th column which we will call happiness.

```
require(gtools)
df1 <- data.frame(permutations(n = 4, r = 4, v = 1:4)) %>% cbind(sample(1:24))
colnames(df1) <- c("Apples", "Pears", "Lemons", "Oranges", "Happiness")
```

However you wish to filter this dataframe to leave only certain combinations of fruit which exist in a second data frame (not with the same column order):

```
df2 = data.frame(Apples = c(1, 3, 2, 4), Pears = c(4, 1, 1, 3), Lemons = c(2, 2, 3, 1), Oranges = c(3, 4, 4, 2))
```

Currently I am using a loop to apply each row of df2 as a filter condition one-by-one and then binding the result e.g:

```
df.ss = list()
for (i in 1:nrow(df2)){

df.ss[[i]] = filter(df1, 
                    df1$Apples == df2$Apples & 
                    df1$Pears == df2$Pears &
                    df1$Lemons == df2$Lemons & 
                    df1$Oranges == df2$Oranges)
}

df.ss %>% bind_rows()
```

Is there a more elegant way of going about this ?

Comment: Where did you get `permutations()` from?

Comment: Oops. See edit now!

Comment: your expected output is the result of `df.ss %>% bind_rows()` ? I'm not sure because there are many duplicated rows

Comment: There’s a curly bracket missing at the end of your code somewhere. Perhaps it is also useful to paste the desired output explicitly here

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for an `inner join`

```
dplyr::inner_join(df1, df2)
```

Comment: What if you had multiple dataframes (similar to df1) and an additional column giving the date - i.e. if you have df1 for each day in a week and you binded the dataframes together. What approach could you use then?

Comment: I was trying the same with merge but this gives different results then his `bind_rows()` ...